# Django CSRF token missing or incorrect but CSFR has been added

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Django give me the following error `CSRF token missing or incorrect.` but I don't find the issue.

I have created my forms:

```
class ModCollaboratoriForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AltriCosti
        fields = "__all__"
```

and my simple views.py:

```
def collaboratori_commessa(request):
    collaboratori_commessa=AltriCosti.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = ModCollaboratoriForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             print("Il form è valido")
             new_input = form.save()

    else :
        form = ModCollaboratoriForm()

    context={
        'form':form,
        'collaboratori_commessa': collaboratori_commessa,
    }
    return render(request, 'commesse/collaboratori_commessa.html', context)
```

And in my collaboratori_commessa.htm the following form:

```
<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" >
      {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="card card-outline card-info shadow ">
                            <div class="card-header ">
                                <h4 class="mb-0">
                                <img src="{% static 'icon/plus-circle.svg' %}"> Informazioni generali
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                {{ form.media }}
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="form-group col-2 0 mb-0" >
                     {{form.codice_commessa|as_crispy_field}}
                 </div>
                 .....
                </div>
             <div class="card-footer">
                 <div class="col-md-2">
                 <button class="btn btn-info form-control" type="submit" onclick="submitForm()">Registra</button>
                 </div>
                </div>
         </form>
```

Why django give me the CSRF Error?

Comment: Try removing `onclick="submitForm()"` - if it works without that, then it looks like the problem is with your JavaScript. The CSRF docs has an [AJAX](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) section that might help.